# HTTP Request Authentication with HMAC standard

Tags: md5, hmac

I was looking for a rfc or some other standard to find out the HMAC signature of a HTTP Request, specially to POST/PUT where body is not empty, I only have found the generic RFC (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2104.txt) but not specifying the case of an HTTP.
We had a look to how other (AWS, Facebook, Twitter) have done it, but each of them have their own solutions, does anybody know the more official standard for that?

Thanks in advance